# What is the use of two not (!!) operator on a variable

Tags: html, geolocation, not-operator

I am following a tutorial on [browser detection](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html#geolocation) which is using two `!!` not operator in return. I want to know what is the significance of using 2 !! in a code.

```
function supports_geolocation() {
  return !!navigator.geolocation;
}
```

I believe `!!navigator.geolocation === navigator.geolocation`.

Correct me if not and let me know the significance of using two not operator here.

Comment: @RHertel What is `as.logical` ?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought this was a question related to `R`. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It force returns boolean value.

```
// navigator.geolocation is GeoLocation object
navigator.geolocation === true // return false
!!navigator.geolocation === true // returns true
```